# How do I open links in Visual Studio in my web browser and not in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, hyperlink

If there is a URL in a source file comment, I can "CTRL + click to follow link."  However, when I do this, the link opens inside Visual Studio.  How can I make it open in my web browser--in my case, Google Chrome?

Comment: I was about to say to file a feature request, but guess what. In VS2010beta1's editor view, the automatic link is actually gone.

Comment: @Bahbar: In VS2010 RC, the links are back.

Comment: Any updates on this question after 2.5 years? Is there a better way now?

Comment: Visual Studio has thousands of options in its labyrinthine options dialog. Surely this is one of them?

Comment: Accepted answer doesn't work for Visual Studio 2012, so opened a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13047914/visual-studio-2012-change-browser

Comment: Vote for this to be fixed in VS [here](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2723548-open-links-in-an-actual-browser).

Comment: Any update on this after 4 years?

Comment: Any update on this after 6 years? :)

Comment: MS is finally taking notice. The UserVoice issue was recently marked as "Under Review".
https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/2723548-open-links-in-an-actual-browser

Comment: Any update on this after 8 years?

Comment: This seems to finally work out of the box.  I'm using VS2017, version 15.3.2, and my only extension/addon is R#.

Comment: VS2019 has it! See answer below for screenshot. CTRL+F my username.

Comment: any updates on this after 12 years?

Comment: In 2019 VS the CTRL + CLICK or even just a straight click say for example clicking a source link in NuGet; opens IE 11. I found that this particular function uses whatever you default browser is in your operating system. Update that and it will start opening in Chrome or whatever you set. To have it open outside of VS is in Tool > Options I believe.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

There is an extension that provides this behavior called [Open in External Browser](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SamHarwell.OpeninExternalBrowser). It works in Visual Studio 2012, 2013, 2015 and 2017. (An old version [available on GitHub](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/OpenInExternalBrowser/releases) supports Visual Studio 2010.)

Thanks goes to [Dmitry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1397902/dmitry) for pointing this out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25440434/219521) to this similar question.

**EDIT: The Visual Studio team is finally starting to work on putting this right into Visual Studio. Status of [this](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/2723548-open-links-in-an-actual-browser?tracking_code=f6f3dac6a2ffabe8ed459c1d0d186b58) feature request just moved from "Under Review" to "Started".**

Comment: Thanks Mike!  A nice, easy solution.

Comment: Thanks for the update Rob. It's a shame that we still need to use this in VS2015.

Comment: Works in VS2017 as well

Comment: For Anyone else wondering it will work for Visual Studio 2019, but I hope they just include it.

Comment: is there an update for Visual Studio 2022? i tried installing the .vsix but it failed :(

Answer (score 7):

I could not find a setting for this so I wrote a simple macro that you can use.  You can bind this to a key-combo like all macros.  This will get the job done until we get a better answer.

```vbs
Sub OpenURLInChrome()
   'copy to end of line
   DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.EndOfLine(True)

  'set var
   Dim url As String = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text

   'launch chrome with url
   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start( _
      Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) _
      + "\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe", url)
End Sub
```

Just put your cursor in front of the url and run the macro...

Comment: I don't have VB installed but it looks like it'll work (if there is nothing at the end of the line past the URL), plus I hate having un-answered questions, so marking as answer. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Sam: You don't need VB installed to use Visual Studio macros. They just use the same syntax.

Comment: Is this something you have to install somehow?

Comment: Turns out Visual Studio 2012 doesn't support macros, that's why I couldn't install it. Try emacs.

Answer (score 5):

This is an improvement on the macro suggested above by mracoker.

This macro looks for a URL on the current line and does not capture text after the URL as the previous answer did.

```vbs
Sub OpenURLInChrome()

   ' Select to end of line
   DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.EndOfLine(True)
   Dim selection As TextSelection = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection

   ' Find URL within selection
   Dim match = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match( _
      selection.Text, ".*(http\S+)")

   Dim url As String = ""
   If (match.Success) Then
      If match.Groups.Count = 2 Then
         url = match.Groups(1).Value
      End If
   End If

   ' Remove selection
   selection.SwapAnchor()
   selection.Collapse()

   If (url = String.Empty) Then
       MsgBox("No URL found")
   End If

   ' Launch chrome with url
   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start( _
      Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) _
      + "\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe", url)
End Sub
```

To use: place cursor somewhere before the URL; Run Macro (I mapped to Ctrl-Shift-G)

Answer (score 0):

**2019 Update:** All the answers are old. There's now a native way to do this in options in VS2019 Community:

[image: Options >> Web Browser]

Comment: This doesn't appear to do anything for opening clickable links in files.
Tried it, not sure what it does. Doesn't appear to do anything.

Comment: That has been there since at least VS2012, and nothing in the image you show there has anything to do with configuring a browser. From the docs: "
[Sets the **editor** used to open a Web page **when you choose View Source on the page from the internal Web browser**."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/web-browser-environment-options-dialog-box?view=vs-2019). It's for viewing the source, not for preventing it from opening stuff in the internal browser in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me. I changed the default browser in Windows.

[Windows-Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028606/windows-10-change-your-default-browser)

or direct link to settings: **ms-settings:defaultapps**

Answer (score -4):

In VS2008 , just right click on the link and select "Open link in external window". You have to select Chrome as your default browser.

Comment: I thought of this too, but it does not apply to links directly in the source code, only to links in, say, the Help.

Comment: You're right only links in the internal navigator not in the source code pane.

Comment: -1 does not answer the question. :-)... If anyone has a solution that does not involve right click menu or CTRL click that would be even better :-)