# azure download subscription file link

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure

I am trying to publish website following the link in the http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/web-site-with-sql-database/. However when I try to download the subscription file as mentioned in this link, the download link opens in the Visual Studio browser window (a new browse tab opens in Visual Studio) itself. I need to change it to open it in IE or Chrome.

I tried to change the start external program of the project to IE, as mentioned in one of the post but it did not help. Could you pls. suggest anything to help.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using IE or Chrome, you can just right-click on the "Download publish profile" and choose "Save link as" on Step 3, Section "Deploy the application to Windows Azure".

[image: Download publisher profile for Azure]

Then you don't need to click the link in Visual Studio or reset your default browser preferences.

**UPDATE:**
Concerning the Visual Studio opening the link with a built-in browser, unfortunately you can't change it now, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13047914/visual-studio-2012-change-web-browser) for more details.

Comment: Thanks Alexander! This works. Oddly enough, I had tried to import it the way you mentioned but that failed so I was trying to download it using subscription link. I must have tried it wrongly earlier.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to change settings so Visual Studio does not open browser tab in its own ID?

Comment: @vibhu: This is not possible AFAIK. I edited my answer and added a link to another SO question treating this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The link below to download you Subscription details no longer works:
https://windows.azure.com/download/publishprofile.aspx

The updated link to download your Azure Subscription details is:
https://manage.windowsazure.com/publishsettings