# How change that default "web browser" (that is embed in Visual C++)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

In the Visual Studio 2013 and earlier versions as well (Visual C++ to be precisely), when I add to the source code such line:

```
//see more at http://documnetation/thisclass
```

And then hover over the link in comment, I get the tooltip *ctrl + click to follow*. And when I do *ctrl + click*, the website opens in a new tab (inside Visual Studio, which is great).

**I wonder, can I change that default "web browser" to render page with e.g. Firefox (still inside the Visual Studio)?** It's not even my actual IE engine (browsing the page with IE gives different look then with Visual Studio's "something").

**Note:** I'm not speaking about the default web browser for debugging/running a web site (dont' get confused).

I have found the info about opening with another web browser, **but not inside the Visual Studio**:
[Visual Studio 2012 change web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13047914/visual-studio-2012-change-web-browser)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot alter the browser that's used; Visual Studio uses the Win32 Web Control, which embeds the rendering core of Internet Explorer.

Fortunately, this uses the version of Internet Explorer that you have installed, so if you have a current version (and you should!) then it will use that version.  Unfortunately, the Web Control uses different defaults than Internet Explorer itself.  As a result, it may render your page in some horrible compatibility mode.

If you have access to the HTML being rendered, you can force the web control to act like a modern browser with the compatibility header:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

Comment: Thank you for the complex answer instead of simple "you cannot" statement. In fact, it worked well in my case (I at least have exactly the same result on my IE and VS embed browser now).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot.

The tab contains a Windows browser control using the IE engine — you cannot make an arbitrary, distinct program (i.e. another browser of your choice) run inside that tab.

Comment: Hm, that's sad. Anyway, why my IE renders the website in a different way then what I get inside Visual Studio? That differences are huge, like another version of IE - I mean, it looks like previewed in much older IE (inside VS 2013). Maybe I can at least change that to render the same way as in my (currently installed and default) IE (from Windows 7).

Comment: The documentation for VS was written and checked with that IE version in mind, so it's not surprising that the IE control is set to an old rendering mode.

Comment: @PolGraphic: It's probably an antiquated control. I'm curious as to why you care, frankly: it makes all the sense in the world to simply follow the advice in the question you linked us to, and set VS to open webpages in a proper browser.

Comment: @MatteoItalia The web control uses the same renderer as IE, but it has a different compatibility mode.  Make sure that `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />` is in your document.

Comment: @EdwardThomson: As IE what though? Does it use the engine of the IE that's installed?

Comment: Yes, the control simply embeds IE (the version that's installed), it doesn't provide a whole second copy of the rendering engine.

Comment: @EdwardThomson: Adding the `<meta...>` worked perfectly and eliminated the differences :) (ah, that lovely IE and compatibility modes that make it even more non-compatible :P) And thank you for an explanation, I've up-voted your comments.

Comment: Glad you were able to change the HTML itself - the last time I waded into this madness, I was consuming somebody else's.

Comment: @EdwardThomson Probably worth writing that in an answer then? Mods like to nuke comments.