# Where is the browser switcher in visual studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I cant find the browser switcher, does anyone know how Id be able to add this to my toolbar.

[image]

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201570/how-do-i-open-links-in-visual-studio-in-my-web-browser-and-not-in-visual-studio

Comment: It's just a little to the left of the center in your screenshot. Or - what is your question? The dropdown you show _is_ the browser switcher. Or do you mean you don't see it? What kind of project do you have opened?

Comment: I dont see it at all. its an mvc3 project but cant see it in the toolbar or the options.

Comment: Do you have a "normal" start button?

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio Express?

Comment: visual studio professional, I have the play green flash but the dropdown isnt there.

Comment: The browser switcher is part of the Standard toolbar.  To display the Standard toolbar, open the View menu, locate Toolbars towards the bottom, and select the checkbox next to Standard.