# CTRL+Clicking commented URLs and open in external browsers

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Right now when I <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+Click a URL, it opens up a tab within my VS 2013 (I assume it uses IE).  Is there a way to change the behavior to open the URL with the browser of my choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201570/how-do-i-open-links-in-visual-studio-in-my-web-browser-and-not-in-visual-studio). It is a work-around but it might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the answer. I don't think I'll be setting up a macro on this machine, but it doesn't look like there's another known solution, so I'll be marking this as the answer.